# How to test a component that alters styling onclick

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, jestjs

I am trying to test a menu button which brings out an overlay of nav links (onClick) which is another component. But I keep getting this error. `TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style')`. So judging off the Error I assume the style object is a problem and I dont even understand why. Is this something I should try to mock? and if yes, How?. I appreciate any help on this. I have the code of the component and its test file below.

```js
// Nav.js fie
import "../../styles/Nav.sass";
import { useState } from "react";

const Nav = () => {
    const [navIsExpanded, setNavIsExpanded] = useState(false);
    return (
        <button
            className="nav-button"
            onClick={() => {
                const navOverlay = document.getElementById("layer");
                if (navIsExpanded) {
                    setNavIsExpanded(false);
                    navOverlay.style.left = "-80vw";
                } else {
                    setNavIsExpanded(true);
                    navOverlay.style.left = "0vw";
                }
            }}
        >
            {navIsExpanded ? "CLOSE" : "MENU"}
        </button>
    );
};
export default Nav;
```

This is what I've been able to come up with so far.

```js
// Nav.test.js
import React from "react";
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import "@testing-library/jest-dom"; // optional
import userEvent from "@testing-library/user-event";
import Nav from "../Components/Nav/Nav";

describe("Menu Button Component", () => {
    it("changes it's textContent onclick", () => {
        render(<Nav />);
        const navButton = screen.getAllByRole("button");
        userEvent.click(navButton[0]);

        expect(setStateMock.mock.calls).toHaveLength(1);
    });
});
```

Comment: Maybe try [Cypress](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/visual-testing#Functional-vs-visual-testing)

Answer (score 0):

Inside the button component you access the `navOverlay.style.left` where `navOverlay` is defined as `const navOverlay = document.getElementById("layer");`

In your test you render the button, but `navOverlay` is not rendered. `document.getElementById()` returns null if the element cannot be found. The jest documentation has an example [here](https://jestjs.io/docs/tutorial-jquery) about testing functions that modify DOM content.

Comment: Hmm… makes a lot of sense… thanks so much! I’ll try it

Comment: Update: It worked.. thanks. All I had to do was render the overlay in the tests to getElementById() could actually pick it up from the DOM... or VirtualDOM :D